# Multiple h tags breaks div

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code. It works when using one H tag inside the div´s.
The moment I insert another H tag in one div, that div seems to break the rest
of the code. I use inline-block, so the div´s align properly. The div with the 
extra H tag pushes down the other two div´s and alignment is gone.

BTW, all margins are set to 0, so that is not the problem.
Also, setting the H tags to inline element did not help.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

```
   #content-2 {
     width:980px;
     margin:0 auto;
    }
    #content-2 div {
     display:inline-block;
     height:400px;
     width:33%;
    }


    <div id="content-2">

    <div>
    <h3>Bla</h3>
    <h3>Bla</h3>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h3>Bla</h3>
    </div>

    <div>
    <h3>Bla</h3>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: don't use "inline-block", simple as that.

Comment: But then the div´s within the content-2 div aren´t adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either float the divs or use `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: Just as an info to mooizo: The `h` elements didn't break anything. That's how `inline-block` works by default. Don't assume something is "buggy" or "broken", just because it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Sorry for not using proper English, im not a native speaker - it breaks the design, so in that sense it `breaks` something. Thank you for you kind answer rotora - but it has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure what causes the other divs to be pushed down. It happens with `<p>`'s or `<span>`'s instead of `<h3>`'s as well, so it's not just the headings that do it.

Giving the `<div>`'s inside `#content-2` a `float:left` seems to fix the problem, does that work for you?

Comment: yes, that seems to work, but then they break out of the surrounding content-2 div. Half way!

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` then doing `inline block`